# Laravel 5 dropdown box do not pass back old value upon validation fail

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have a quick question. I made a dropdown box for gender selection in my registration form that looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <select name="gender" value="{{ old('gender') }}" class="form-control">
        <option value=null>------ Gender ------</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>
    {!! MessagerService::setInlineError($errors->first('gender')) !!}
</div>
```

So what I do is upon a validation fail, the selected gender is not passed back to the form. Any ideas what I have done wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You have to make the comparison in the option tag. It should be `selected` if its value matches `old('gender')`. Something like `old('gender') == male ? 'selected' : ''`, this should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to write plain HTML. You can take advantage of Laravel Form Builder. In Laravel 5 it is not bundled by default, like it was in 4.2, so first you need to require it. Go to your project root and in terminal write:

```
composer require "illuminate/html":"5.0.*"
```

Then go to `config/app.php` and under `providers` add

```
'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

You can register also those two facades under `aliases`:

```
'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 
'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

After that you are ready to use `Form` facade to create your select with one simple line of code which will handle old input values:

```
{!! Form::select('gender', ['' => '--Gender--', 'male' => 'Male', 'female' => 'Female']) !!}
```

It is as simple as that. You can check the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html) to find out more useful methods of the `Form` facade.

Comment: ok, it works with 5.1. That day I did something wrong probably

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without using laravel form builder?